# Exporting last row in CSV file using VBScript

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I am still a novice when it comes to Scripting so please forgive me if this is a simple error on my part.

I am trying to display the last row in a constantly updated CSV file using a VBS script I created and execute with CMD. I have been pulling and tinkering with code from multiple sources.

So far, I can only get it to pull the top row and can't figure out how to switch it to the bottom. My code is a little rough. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel
Dim excelPath
Dim workSheetCount
Dim counter
Dim currentWorkSheet
Dim usedRowsCount
Dim row
Dim top
Dim Cells
Dim curRow
Dim word


excelPath = "c:\Test\test.csv"

WScript.Echo "Reading Data from " & excelPath

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
objExcel.Workbooks.open excelPath, false, true

workSheetCount = objExcel.Worksheets.Count

WScript.Echo "We have " & workSheetCount & " worksheets"

For counter = 1 to workSheetCount
WScript.Echo "-----------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "Reading data from worksheet " & counter & vbCRLF

Set currentWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter)

usedRowsCount = currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
top = currentWorksheet.UsedRange.Row

Set Cells = currentWorksheet.Cells
For row = 0 to (usedRowsCount-1)
    curRow = row+top
    word = Cells(curRow).Value
    WScript.Echo (word)
Next
Next

Set currentWorkSheet = Nothing
objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close
objExcel.Quit
Set currentWorkSheet = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm...

```
filename = "C:\Test\test.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f   = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    line = f.ReadLine
Loop

f.Close

WScript.Echo line
```

CSV is a text format, so you can easily process it with `FileSystemObject` methods without involving Excel.

Comment: Thank you! Comparing, i see i was doing a lot of unnecessary scripting.